# Shopify App Url Update Issue For Development

Tags: shopify

I am trying to develop an app by using webhooks. I configured my app and started to develop. For first 30 mins, everything was fine but then my webhook started to not working. When I check app insights, it seems it is sending webhook request to another URL;

It is webhook request;

App Url Update Issue For Development

[image]

It is actually configured URL;

[image]

It happened 3-4 times for me while developing and there is no fix. Just it is fixing automatically after 2-3 hours, and it is really disturbing and frustrating. Looking for a solution.

Comment: are you using ngrok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definetely a bug on Shopify side. I solved it by using cloudflared. It is stabile and there are no issue anymore.